# Azure AD and Office 365 authorization/authentication flow

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, office365-apps

I've a silly doubt related to Azure AD authentication and Office 365 provider hosted app/add-in authentication.As mainly there are two authentication ways for Azure AD resource access

1. Authorization Grant flow ( user based /delegated permission )
2. Client Credential flow (app-only /admin consent)

Which of above is used by provider hosted add-in for Authorization/Authentication?

If none of the above,then what kind of flow it uses to authorize/authenticate users against Azure AD?

Under the permission section of provider hosted add-in ,there is a check box for **app only**.Is it same as Client Credential flow **app-only** or related to Azure AD **app-only** grant flow by any other way?